# Referring to other instance of class A in class A

Tags: c++, class, object, header, incomplete-type

I'm having this (part of) code in my header

```
class Node
{
     Node prevNode;

     public:
     Node(float nodeXRotation, float nodeYRotation, 
         float nodeZRotation, float boneLength, float xOffset, 
         Node prevnode);
}
```

But its giving me the following error: IntelliSense: incomplete type is not allowed 
(on line 3: Node prevNode;)

This is where I initialize the 'Nodes'

```
Node nodes[] = {    Node(0, 0, 0, 5, -14, NULL),     //Duimkootje 2
                Node(0, 0, 0, 5, -9, nodes[0]),  //Duimkootje 1
                    Node(0, 0, 0, 10, 0, nodes[1]), //DUIMHANDBOT



             Node(0, 25, 0, 10, 0), //WIJSVINGERHANDBOT
                Node(0, 25, 0, 8, -9, nodes[3]),  //Wijsvingerkootje 1
                Node(0, 25, 0, 7, -17, nodes[4]),  //Wijsvingerkootje 2
                 Node(0, 25, 0, 7, -24, nodes[5]),  //Wijsvingerkootje 3

             Node(0, 50, 0, 10, 0), //MIDDELVINGERHANDBOT
                 Node(0, 50, 0, 8, -9, nodes[7]), //Middelvingerkootje 1
                 Node(0, 50, 0, 8, -17, nodes[8]), //Middelvingerkootje 1
                 Node(0, 50, 0, 8, -24, nodes[9]), //Middelvingerkootje 1

             Node(0, 75, 0, 10, 0), //RINGVINGERHANDBOT
                 Node(0, 75, 0, 7, -9, nodes[11]), //Ringvingerkootje 1
                 Node(0, 75, 0, 8, -16, nodes[12]), //Ringvingerkootje 1
                 Node(0, 75, 0, 8, -24, nodes[13]), //Ringvingerkootje 1

             Node(0, 100, 0, 10, 0), //PINKHANDBOT
                 Node(0, 100, 0, 5, -9, nodes[15]), //Pinkkootje 1
                 Node(0, 100, 0, 5, -14, nodes[16]), //Pinkkootje 1
                 Node(0, 100, 0, 6, -19, nodes[17]), //Pinkkootje 1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A `Node` cannot contain a `Node`, that would require an infinite amount of memory.  Instead, make it contain either a reference or a pointer to another `Node`. (Probably pointer, reference members make things tricky)

Comment: Also: intellisense errors are not real errors.  Run the compiler, and give full error messages from the "Output Window" (Not the "Error Window"!)

Comment: ... and so, [ad infiitum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Siphonaptera).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mooing Duck has the answer in a comment.  The problem comes in because you haven't fully defined a Node when you're trying to define one.  This means that the compiler can't determine how much memory to allocate.

The solution is do make `prevNode` a `Node*`, because then you are declaring something with a known size.

Interestingly, if you're coming to C++ from Java., you *can* get away with this in java.  This is because any declaration like that in Java is *always* an object reference.  You don't need to have size information, because what you are doing is always going to "point to" something, not allowcate space for something.  That's also why, in Java, you  invariably want to do `Foo x = new Foo()`.

Comment: How would I have to change my constructor, since I can't use Node(0, 0, 0, 5, -14, NULL),  //Duimkootje 2
     Node(0, 0, 0, 5, -9, nodes[0]),  //Duimkootje 1
      Node(0, 0, 0, 10, 0, nodes[1])............

Comment: But if you make `prevNode` a `Node*`, there's no reason you can't, and it's just what I'd do.  The NULL marks a node for which there is no previous.

Comment: Are you not missing a `new` in the last line there?

Comment: Yeah and weirdly I remember typing it.  Well, I got it now.